# Concatenation of undef and list is undef - proof Haskell

Tags: haskell, undefined, proof

How could one prove that the following is true for every list xs:

```
undefined ++ xs = undefined
```

Comment: I've edited the question body so that it matches your title (since I judged the title to make more sense than the body). Do feel free to re-edit if I've incorrectly guessed what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not much to prove. There is simply a rule (which can't be explained or broken down into anything smaller) that `case` statements which try to match `undefined` against a constructor result in `undefined`. Once you accept this rule, we can observe

```
undefined ++ ys
= { by definition of ++ }
case undefined of
    [] -> ys
    x:xs -> x : (xs ++ ys)
= { case that matches undefined against a constructor }
undefined
```